# How to close the small editor window when injecting language reference in intellij?

Tags: string, intellij-idea, editor

As suggested by [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html) document, I'm using language injection feature to edit strings with intellij.

But my problem is even after my work done and un-injecting the language reference, (as per '7.' mentioned in the documentation), the small editor window appearing (which can be seen by '6.' in the documentation) is still not getting closed.

Is there any key combination or any other way to close it easily?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the standard window close shortcut (applicable to any windows within IntelliJ) usually this is `CTRL F4` but you can work out what your mapping is by having a look at `Preferences > Keymap > Window > Editor Tabs > Close`.

[image: close editor keymap]

Or - less conveniently - you could click the `x` close icon in the fragment editor tab.

[image: fragment editor tab]

Hitting the ESC key to close the `Edit Fragment` window sounds appealing but that was [rejected](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162328).